# PThread Mutex Not Working as Hoped

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, mutex

I'm using mutexes to try to restrict access to certain part of the codes to one thread, but instead of locking once and blocking the others, it seems to allow all threads to "lock". Following is my code, and then a section of the output showing that the code is not working.

```
//headers defined, etc

pthread_mutex_t queuemutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

// other code with various functions

int main(void) {

    //unrelated code

    threadinformation **threadArray = (threadinformation **)malloc( POOLSIZE * sizeof(threadinformation) );

    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < POOLSIZE; k++) {
        pthread_t thread;
        threadinformation *currentThread = (threadinformation *)malloc(sizeof(threadinformation));
        currentThread->state = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        currentThread->state[0] = 0;
        currentThread->currentWaiting = currentWaiting;
        currentThread->number = k;
        threadArray[k] = currentThread;
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, readWriteToClient, threadArray[k]); //thread is created here
        currentThread->thread = thread;
        joinArray[k] = thread;
    }

    //unrelated code

}

static void* readWriteToClient(void *inputcontent) {

    while(1){

        //unrelated code

        pthread_mutex_lock(&queuemutex); //problem happens here

        fprintf(stderr,"Thread %d got locked \n",threadInput->number);

        while((threadInput->currentWaiting->status) == 0){
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &queuemutex);
            fprintf(stderr,"Thread %d got signalled \n",threadInput->number);
        }

        connfd = threadInput->currentWaiting->fd;
        threadInput->currentWaiting->status = 0;
        pthread_cond_signal(&conncond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queuemutex);

        //unrelated code

    }

}
```

Output.

```
Thread 0 got locked 
Thread 7 got locked 
Thread 25 got locked 
Thread 97 got locked 
Thread 6 got locked 
Thread 5 got locked 
Thread 4 got locked 
Thread 3 got locked 
Thread 8 got locked 
Thread 9 got locked 
Thread 10 got locked 
Thread 11 got locked 
Thread 12 got locked 
Thread 13 got locked 
Thread 14 got locked 
Thread 15 got locked 
Thread 16 got locked 
Thread 17 got locked 
Thread 18 got locked 
Thread 19 got locked 
Thread 20 got locked 
    And so on...
```

Comment: Is threadinput->currentwaiting->status declared volatile?

Comment: you should consider deleting that question now that the other got an answer!

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem.

pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &queuemutex);

waiting on a condition variable RELEASES the mutex.

Comment: And just as important, it re-aquires it when pthread_cond_wait returns

Answer (score 1):

The longer version of what fceller said is that, pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex) does three things before it returns:  It releases the lock, and then it waits for a signal, and then it waits (if necessary) to re-acquire the lock.

Your example does not show what (if anything) ever sends the first signal, and it does not show what (if anything) ever sets the status that the worker threads are waiting for.

Here is a more typical use-case for pthread_cond_wait() and pthread_cond_signal().

```
void producer() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    push_something_on_the_queue();
    ptherad_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void consumer() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (! time_to_quit) {
        if (queue_is_empty) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        } else {
            thing = take_something_from_the_queue();

            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            do_something_with(thing);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

A producer thread puts things in a queue.  A consumer thread waits for things to appear in the queue, and then it pops them off and does something with them.  The consumer waits in a loop, and it checks the status of the queue each time it wakes up (A thread may be "falsely" signalled even when there is nothing in the queue).

The mutex is locked when the consumer is checking the queue, and it remains locked until the consumer either sleeps or pops a thing off the queue. The mutex is *not* locked while the consumer is sleeping, and it is not locked while the consumer is doing whatever it does with a thing.

Any number of consumers can be in the consumer() method at the same time.  They may be operating on different things, or they may be sleeping; but the mutex is insures that no more than one thread (producer or consumer) can touch the queue at any given time.